# How to get most recently downloaded file in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi this code currently gets the most recent file in the dir it is ran in. How can this be adapted to get the most recent file in a path set by a variable?

Code:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var getMostRecent = function (dir, cb) {
    var dir = path.resolve(dir);
    var files = fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        var sorted = files.map(function(v) {
            var filepath = path.resolve(dir, v);
            return {
                name:v,
                time:fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime()
            }; 
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.time - a.time; })
        .map(function(v) { return v.name; });

        if (sorted.length > 0) {
            cb(null, sorted[0]);
        } else {
            cb('Y U NO have files in this dir?');
        }
    })
}

getMostRecent('./', function (err, recent) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(recent);
});
```

Comment: You change the first parameter in the function call.. `getMostRecent(someVariable, ...)`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Thanks. Iol. looked at it quickly.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. how do I save the variable recent to a variable for use? Im getting lastdownloadedimage  undefined errors.
var recent;


getMostRecent(downloadanduploadPath, function (err, recent) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  console.log(recent);
  return recent;
 });
  var lastdownloadedimage = recent;

Comment: it's already usable. put some code in the callback function and use it.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. stackoverflow.com/questions/63291821/how-to-save-the-return-value-to-a-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Credit to @Iwrestledabearonce for his comment of the solution. Thank you to him***

You would change the

> "./"

in the

> getMostRecent()

function.

**example:**

```
var directory = "C:/Users/computerturtle/Downloads/";

getMostRecent(directory, function (err, recent);
```